# How can I improve page loading speed when its empty?

Tags: apache, performance, http, pagespeed

This is somewhat of a hard question, as I've been working to fix this for quite some time now, but I am running out of ideas.

The problem: The loading time for the page takes to long. It looks kinda "creepy". I've already compressed files, moved them together and all of this. But I am having a major problem, which I found no answer of:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSvO3.jpg

I've removed some parts which delayed the page loading already. However, as you can see, from 600ms to 800ms and ~900ms to ~1500ms is completely empty. Nothing is loading. Thats almost 800s of a total of 1.88s loading time, which the page doesn't do anything.

How can I remove that empty space?

Comment: are you loading javascript src in the head or at the end of the body? Have you considered hosting the document and images on a CDN? that typically speeds their load time as well.

Comment: I am loading them in the head. When I move them to the lower body, overall loading time increases by 500ms. Images are hosted on S3.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no JS in the page which is timed to delay subsequent requests? It doesn't look like any requests are pending during those gaps, so the question is, what _is_ happening in those periods?

Comment: loading them in the head causes them to finish running their script before all the elements finish loading, leading to your "creepy" look. I would try using the post below this "google pagespeed" using it in both the head and at the bottom of the body, and see what score they give you both ways.

Comment: I've tried this already. At the end, as I said, I got an additional 500ms. I've actually uploaded it to production servers. It works, kind of. There are 600ms less than previous. Looks like it was only having trouble with localhost for some reason. Some empty spaces still, but I'm happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free tool provided by Google for ideas on improving page loading times for mobile and desktop:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en&url=https%3A%2F%2Fm.imgur.com%2FjKzc7uy&tab=desktop

Comment: This doesn't really help my case. I am actively using that tool already. :(

Comment: I think it might be some JavaScript that is preventing any other event from happening